# What tables should i create

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have to do a project for a university course.
This project is about the creation of multiple choices (MC).
So one user can submit a number of MCs (packed in a quiz), and then another user can take the said quiz.
Each question and each answer can either be in the form of text or they can be in the form of an image or even a video.
So how should i design my SQL schema?

I have the tables:
Question(questionID,..)
Answer(answerID,...)

And i don't know how to associate them with the Media Table that has the plaint text or the link if it's an image or video.

Should i just have one table like:
Media(mediaID,type,content), where type has the value 0 for text,1 for image, 2 for video

and then
hasMedia(mediaID,correspondingID) where it would either be the id of the question or the answer.

or make the table hasMedia like this:
hasMedia(mediaID,questionID,answerID) and put a 0 in the questionID or the answerID, if it is not referred to them?

OR make different tables that hold the Media for the Questions and different Media tables for the Answers like:
MediaQuestion(mediaID,type,content)
hasMediaQuestion(mediaID,questionID)
and
MediaAnswer(mediaID,type,content)
hasMediaAnswer(mediaID,questionID)

Or something different entirely??

[This is the schema for the last scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWAeM.png)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: A video would be a valid answer?

Comment: The first option (just one Media table)  sounds like the simplest and most normalised. Also do you need a hasMedia table? Can one question (or one answer) have more than one media item associated with it, or not? Could the question / answer tables not just have a foreign key to Media directly? P.S. Out of interest, how would a link to an image or video be considered a valid answer? Or is it just something to display if they answer correctly?

Comment: 4 answers are displayed to the user and he chooses the correct one. For (a simple) example there is the question : which color is the blue one ? The answers are images of 4 different colors and the user chooses one. And yes there is only one media per question, so a foreign key on the question table seems legit. I just wasn't sure if it was in a normalized form.. So thank you for helping me